# Git Bash некорректное отображение русского текста

Tags: python, кодировка, git-bash

Git bash отображает напечатанный русский текст через символ "▒", причем на ввод текст отображается нормально:

[image: Git Bash]

текст `test.py`:

```py
print('привет мир')
```

Как исправить? Тут дело в кодировке Git Bash или в кодировке `test.py` или вообще в чём?

Comment: В какой кодировке файл `test.py`? Какая версия питона? Если сохраняете вывод в файл `python test.py > out.txt` и открываете потом `out.txt` в текстовом редакторе, где можна указать кодировку, то все отображается нормально?

Comment: все файлы в utf-8 версия питона 3.9.0, но out.txt в windows-1251, ничего не понимаю...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше поздно, чем никогда: если вдруг кто-нибудь с этим столкнётся, то помогает выбор CP1251 в кодировке, а в формате ru_RU.
Связка ru_RU и UTF-8 почему-то не спасает.
А вот так работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]